# MVC path and angularjs route merged

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an angularjs MVC application which posts a form to a different domain and a call back comes to MVC controller function as plain http post as below.

http://localhost:58999/Callback

I have Callback() function implemented in HomeController which displays a view and this view loads an angular controller which navigates to a different state upon processing some data.

```
$state.go('conf', {}, { location: true });
```

Once it navigates to 'conf' state, it displays the appropriate view tied to the state but the url becomes http://localhost:58999/Callback#/conf

How can I make it look http://localhost:58999/#/conf without 'Callback' in the url? Because when I refresh the page, it calls the MVC controller function 'Callback' which is not right.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Could you please share your `conf` state configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [$locationService HTML5 mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#-location-service-configuration)

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```